# Crab Nebula short story from 1960s or '70s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

An alien, though human like, race escapes from their dying world on a FTL ship and land on Earth in prehistory, settling peaceably and mating with the natives (possibly in Ancient Egypt).  The story post script has a Chinese astronomer witnessing the 1054 Crab Nebula supernova and proclaiming it as a portent of miracles - the text says the miracle is already here and lies in seven of his genes.

I thought it might be an Arthur C Clarke story, but I can't find it amongst his output.  I read the story in 1976.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

["...And All the Stars a Stage"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40042) by James Blish.

> 1086 A.D.: A sudden glare of light in the constellation later called
> Taurus. The Chinese astronomer T'ang Yaou-Shun marks it down: *A new
> and marvelous star, portending miracles.*
> But the miracle has already
> happened. It sleeps inside Yaou-Shun, in twelve of his genes.

At one point, the serial was scheduled to be retitled CRAB NEBULA for its book reprint publication (but this did not happen).  See [this source](http://rrhorton.blogspot.com/2016/01/a-mostly-forgotten-sf-novel-and-all.html).

Comment: Can't say how much I appreciate that.  I see the supernova was in Taurus, which makes me think that Blish was thinking of the Crab Nebula, even though he got the date slightly wrong.  And not a short story after all - how fallible is memory!

Comment: @MichaelCPrice You can read the magazine serial at the Internet Archive, in the [June 1960](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v34n06_1960-06_UnkSc-cape1736#mode/2up) and [July 1960](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v34n07_1960-07_cape1736#mode/2up) issues of *Amazing*.